# kendo grid send json to controller

Tags: javascript, .net, kendo-grid

I'm sending a json from kendo grid when I delete a row but in controller I receive null.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: "/Home/GetPatients"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: '@Url.Action("deletePatient", "Home")',
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options)
                                    return kendo.stringify(options);
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "Id",
                                fields: {
                                    FirstName: { type: "string" },
                                    LastName: { type: "string" },
                                    CNP: { type: "string" },
                                    Birthdate: { type: "date" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 20,
                    },
                    height: 300,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true,
                        buttonCount: 5
                    },
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    columns:
                        [
                            { field: "LastName", title: "Nume" },
                            { field: "FirstName", title: "Prenume" },
                            { field: "CNP", title: "CNP" },
                            { field: "Birthdate", title: "Data nasterii", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" },
                            {
                                command:
                                    [
                                        {
                                            name: "edit"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            name: "destroy",
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    title: "", width: "172px"
                            }
                        ],
                    editable: "popup"
                });
            });
```

I put debug here in method and actual parameter 'j' is null, it should be a string (serialize json).
In chrome -> debug mode -> network -> I got status 200 ok and in request payload I view the json with all row data, which fact is ok but I'm stuck.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult deletePatient(string j)
{
    //List<Patient> objName = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Patient>>(j);
    int a = 5;
    a = a - 4;
    return Json(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a string and pretend that it is JSON (see your `contentType` and `data`). It might work if you would change it to something like `text/plain`.

But you shouldn't even try this! You should create a `PatientModel` in C# which has the properties `FirstName`, `LastName` and so on and expect this very model in your controller method. That way you do not have to serialize and deserialize the data yourself. Considering that you already have an action `GetPatients`, I'd guess you already have that model. Use it.

Comment: It's a single-page application, i don't use models in html, data transport between server and client must be json, is more efficient than mvc .net in terms of data loading time, I have a lot of data. I'm using entity framework on server.

Comment: I fix it, apparently it deserialize automatically, I changed `string` to `patient`, `patient` is a class, model.